# Data Table filtering using react-data-table-component

Tags: reactjs, datatable, filtering

I need to convert the below code to normal class component without hooks, can anyone help me with this,
here is the link which i am referring to 
https://jbetancur.github.io/react-data-table-component/?path=/story/filtering--example-1
I need to do filtering without using hooks as i am using only class component.
Below are the versions I am using:-
    "react-data-table-component": "^6.9.3",
    "react": "^16.12.0",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think This is what you are looking for...

```
 class BasicTable extends React.PureComponent {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { filterText: "", resetPaginationToggle: false };
        this.filteredItems = fakeUsers.filter(
          (item) =>
            item.name && item.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterText.toLowerCase())
        );
      }

      handleClear = () => {
        const { resetPaginationToggle, filterText } = this.state;

        if (this.state.filterText) {
          this.setState({
            resetPaginationToggle: !resetPaginationToggle,
            filterText: ""
          });
        }
      };

      getSubHeaderComponent = () => {
        return (
          <FilterComponent
            onFilter={(e) => {
              let newFilterText = e.target.value;
              this.filteredItems = fakeUsers.filter(
                (item) =>
                  item.name &&
                  item.name.toLowerCase().includes(newFilterText.toLowerCase())
              );
              this.setState({ filterText: newFilterText });
            }}
            onClear={this.handleClear}
            filterText={this.state.filterText}
          />
        );
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <DataTable
            title="Contact List"
            columns={columns}
            data={this.filteredItems}
            pagination
            paginationResetDefaultPage={this.state.resetPaginationToggle} // optionally, a hook to reset pagination to page 1
            subHeader
            subHeaderComponent={this.getSubHeaderComponent()}
            selectableRows
            persistTableHead
          />
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: It is not working i added FilterComponent constant also but not able to see search box option

Comment: one small correction {this.getSubHeaderCompnent()} now filterComponent is coming

Comment: Fixed that, if it is working fine then you can mark the answer correct  and I hope you get enough inputs to convert other components from functional to class-based

Comment: I have got inputs for converting functional to class-based,thank you.Can you send me some reference from which I can convert functional to class-based easily ?

Comment: One more doubt here they are searching based on name I am getting dynamic columns so i need to search based on all columns.Do you have any idea how to do that ?

Comment: @Kalyan In order to convert Hooks based component to class-based you need to understand some Hooks like [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) and their counterpart lifecycle method or constructs in class-based component.
I still not understand why do you need functional to class-based conversion, React itself encouraging to move to functional based from class based and preferring to write new component as functional comp instead of class one in your old application

Comment: They have used class based component in my application,I am adding new features to it so I cant change whole class now..

Comment: I get FilterComponent is not defined, should I write a component for it myself?

Comment: FilterComponent is mentioned here: https://jbetancur.github.io/react-data-table-component/?path=/story/examples-filtering--filtering You can create a similar implementation.

Answer (score 9):

You can filter in the component itself

```
<DataTable
    pagination="true"
    columns={columns}
    data={leaderBoardList.filter((item) => {
      if (searchTerm === "") {
        return item;
      } else if (
        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
      ) {
        return item;
      }
    })}
  />
```