# Ensure that data is initialized before filtering method

Tags: reactjs

Trying to do filtering on datatable based on this answer: [Data Table filtering using react-data-table-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62274407/data-table-filtering-using-react-data-table-component)

Filtering is successful. But before filtering, **this.filteredItems is not defined.**

1. If i use data=`{this.filteredItems}`, it will show undefined but once i filter, data will start showing
2. If i use `data={result}`, it will show all results but not allow me to filter

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  ... ommitted irrelevant codes

  render() {
    const result = this.props;
    const getSubHeaderComponent = () => (
      <FilterComponent                             
        onFilter={(e) => {
          const newFilterText = e.target.value;
          this.filteredItems = result.filter(        //Filtering works with this.filteredItems
            item => item.name
                && item.name.toLowerCase().includes(newFilterText.toLowerCase())
          );
          this.setState({ filterText: newFilterText });
        }}
        onClear={this.handleClear}
        filterText={this.state.filterText}
      />
    );

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <DataTable
          columns={columns}
          data={this.filteredItems}   // Only if i filter, then data will appear. Else it will be undefined because the original data is from result
          subHeader
          subHeaderComponent={getSubHeaderComponent()}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you can feed the data conditionally

```
       <DataTable
          columns={columns}
          data={this.filteredItems ? this.filteredItems : result}
          subHeader
          subHeaderComponent={getSubHeaderComponent()}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use-case, either display a loader or simply pass an empty array while it fetches, i.e.

```js
if (!this.filteredItems) {
  // placeholder component - use your own
  return <LoaderComponent />
}
```

or

```js
data={this.filteredItems || []}
```

That being said, it seems overall a bad approach and the answer you're copying from the linked thread has pretty bade code quality (i.e. unnecessary class properties declarations and so on).